# AWS ECS will place a maximum of 2 tasks per an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have a simple ECS task that use the bare mininum: 0.5GB Memory, and 0.25VPCU.

The task looks like this:

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:205470457187:task-definition/sample-fargate:6",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "fargate-app",
            "image": "public.ecr.aws/docker/library/httpd:latest",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "fargate-app-80-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "entryPoint": [
                "sh",
                "-c"
            ],
            "command": [
                "/bin/sh -c \"echo '<html> <head> <title>HEllO WORLD!</title> <style>body {margin-top: 40px; background-color: #333;} </style> </head><body> <div style=color:white;text-align:center> <h1>New!</h1> <h2>Congratulations!</h2> <p>Your application is now running on a container in Amazon ECS.</p> </div></body></html>' >  /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html && httpd-foreground\""
            ],
            "environment": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": []
        }
    ],
    "family": "sample-fargate",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXX:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXX:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 6,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
        },
        {
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "256",
    "memory": "512",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "ARM64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "2023-09-25T08:09:24.876Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:user/yahya",
    "tags": []
}
```

I am running a ECS cluster with t4g.large, which has 2VCPU and 8GB RAM.

When I create a service with the above task, with the desired task count as a large number (e.g. 10), I noticed that each server will contain at most 2 tasks, despite the massive amount of memory and VCPU left.

[image]

Why is this?

Note: I am using the binpack placement strategy

*Update*
I noticed this issue seems to occur when VPC Network type is "awsVPC". It's fine when using "bridge".

Comment: Can you share the ECS service config?